# Type hinting in PHPStorm for CakePHP model behavior

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-hinting, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to use auto completion inside a controller for a model with a behavior.

With:

```
/** @var ModelName **/
public $ModelName;
```

it just auto completes anything inside ModelName and:

```
/** @var BehaviorNameBehavior **/
public $ModelName;
```

just auto completes anything inside BehaviorNameBehavior but I think this is somewhat obvious. I've looked at the PHPdoc documentation and I don't see any way to specify two classes to a variable.

There's also the trouble that in CakePHP, the behavior functions first argument is always (Model $model) but that argument is specified internally in the CakePHP framework and its not included when calling the function within a controller/model.

Has anyone been able to get this working?

EDIT: added example

```
class ModelName extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array("BehaviorName");

    public function someModelFunction() {}
}

class BehaviorNameBehavior extends ModelBehavior {
    public function someBehaviorFunction(Model $model, $param) {}
}

class ControllerNameController extends AppController {
    /** @var BehaviorNameBehavior|ModelName $ModelName */

    public $uses = array("ModelName");

    public function someAction() {
        // Type hinting here thinks model should be first parameter but that's not how CakePHP works
        $this->ModelName->someBehaviorFunction("some param value");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"and I don't see any way to specify two classes to a variable."* . `/** @var BehaviorNameBehavior|ModelName **/`

Comment: Ahh thanks for that, that solves problem #1, but it doesn't solve the model parameter inside a behavior function.

Comment: No clue - I'm not using CakePHP myself so cannot say anything without some code samples.

Comment: Added an example for you to see.

Comment: No luck here. None of the general ideas I have had in mind worked. Definitely need somebody with prior Cake experience (that knows framework at good enough level).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to automate behavior completion like that, PhpStorm will always see the actual method signature, which requires the first argument to be of type `Model`.

The only way to supply appropriate code completion for model objects, is by either defining the "inherited" methods one by one via [**the `@method` tag**](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html), ie

```
/**
 * @method returnType someBehaviorFunction(argumentType $param)
 */
class ModelName extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array("BehaviorName");

    public function someModelFunction() {}
}

/**
 * @property ModelName $ModelName
 */
class ControllerNameController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array("ModelName");

    public function someAction() {
        $this->ModelName->someBehaviorFunction("some param value");
    }
}
```

or by using a dummy interface, which is a little more DRY, and easier to create by using PhpStorms refactoring functionality to extract the interface from the behavior class and just modifying it a little bit.

```
/**
 * @internal
 */
interface IBehaviorNameBehaviorStub {
    /**
     * @param argumentType $param
     * @return returnType
     */
    public function someBehaviorFunction($param);
}

/**
 * @property IBehaviorNameBehaviorStub|ModelName $ModelName
 */
class ControllerNameController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array("ModelName");

    public function someAction() {
        $this->ModelName->someBehaviorFunction("some param value");
    }
}
```

**Note** that there seems to be a bug where PhpStorm sometimes won't recognize `@property` tags properly when there is only one! Seems to be a caching issue, adding an additional `@property` tag and removing it later on usually fixes the problem.